# java bind template dynamically

Tags: java, templates, generics

```
ITypeInfo typeInfo = getTypeInfoForName(IDerivedObject.TYPE_NAME);
List<IDerivedObject> objects = this.<IDerivedObject>readAllObjectsOfType(typeInfo);

public <T extends IBaseObject> List<T> readAllObjectsOfType(ITypeInfo typeInfo) throws Exception
{
    return ObjectBuilder.<T>readAllObjects(typeInfo);
}
```

IFF the template is always bound to the exact implementing class (e.g. not IBaseObject) the template parameter T contains the same information as typeInfo. Is there a way to reduce this duplication of information? Is it even a good idea? I'm not sure, because calling

```
ITypeInfo typeInfo = getTypeInfoForName(IDerivedObject.TYPE_NAME);
List<IBaseObject> objects = this.<IBaseObject>readAllObjectsOfType(typeInfo);
```

is legal java and thus if accidentally called would construct only BaseObject portions and not DerivedObject portions.

FWIW this would mean constructing objects from a class defined by a template, requiring something like `Class<T> = T.class`, which is not legal java but is possible to work around per [*Reflecting Generics*](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I decided this was a bad idea, both for the reason i suggested, and because we're going against the natural flow of the language.